# Using jcombobox to return object or variable

Tags: java, arrays, swing, actionlistener, jcombobox

I have 2 comboboxes and I need to make it so that when certain options are selected from the drop down list, certain results are outputted. How do I associate certain string variables  or objects with multiple combobox selections. I'm not asking you to do my homework for me. Just need pointing in the right direction.

```
    public class gui extends JFrame implements ActionListener{

    String[] colour1 = {"red", "blue", "green", "orange", "brown","white", "black", "yellow", "purple", "pink"};
        String[] colour2 = {"red", "blue", "green", "orange", "brown","white", "black", "yellow", "purple", "pink"};

        JComboBox combo1 = new JComboBox(colour1);
        JComboBox combo2 = new JComboBox(colour2);

        JLabel message = new JLabel(); 
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 1));

    public gui() {

         panel.add(combo1);
        panel.add(combo2);
        panel.add(message);
        frame.add(panel);
}
```

I'm using actionPerformed to catch the users input, and then output specific results. At the moment it only takes the value of one combobox and outputs a string. How do i make it take 2.

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
           if(e.getSource() == combo1){
               JCombobox cb = (JComboBox)e.getSource();
           String colours = (String) cb.getSelectedItem();

           switch(colours){
           case "red": message.setText("");
               break;
           case "blue": message.setText("");
               break;
           case "green": message.setText("");
               break;
           case "pink": message.setText("");
               break;
           case "purple":message.setText("");
               break;
           case "white": message.setText("");
               break;
           case "black": message.setText("");
               break;
           case "brown": message.setText("");
               break;
           case "orange": message.setText("");
               break;
           case "yellow": message.setText("");
               break;
           default: message.setText("");
           }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why are you doing same thing for each case?

Comment: Why have you created two arrays having same values?

Comment: You question is not clear. Please explain a bit more.

Comment: The arrays have same values because the string i want to output maybe associated with 2 different colours.
Each case have a different output message that I just have written in yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it was pointed out in the comments, you probably don't need both arrays. When both combo boxes should contain the same values, then you can pass the same array to both combo boxes.

The actual question seems to be aiming at how to perform a specific action depending on the **combination** of the selections of two combo boxes.

I think there are two options for this: You could either store the *combo boxes* as instance variables, or you could store the *selections* of the combo boxes as instance variables. Since you're already storing the combo boxes as instance variables, this should be the easier one to go here. So you could do something like this:

```
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{
    String color1 = (String)combo1.getSelectedItem();
    String color2 = (String)combo2.getSelectedItem();
    // Possibly check if either color is 'null' here

    if (color1.equals("blue") && color2.equals("yellow"))
    {
        message.setText("green");
    }
    ...
}
```

(Note: If you now intend to write a nested switch-statement like

```
switch(colour1)
{
    case "red": 
        switch(colour2)
        {
            // 10 cases...
        }
    break;

    // 10 x 10 cases...
}
```

you should think about a different approach, depending on *what* you want to do with these colors...)

Comment: Thanks for your answer it does work, but it would require I make a lot of if statements to satisfy every possible combination.

Comment: @user3407452 Sure, `if` statements or a `switch` are probably not the appropriate solution here. You should describe (in words, and best as a new question!) what the outcomes should be for the combinations. Then one can make appropriate suggestions of how to solve this. (It will most likely involve some `Map` and or `Set`, and *could* be easy in the best case - except when *each* combination should result in a different value...)

Answer (score 0):

What you want is display a Value depending on the selected Values of the two comboboxes. Make combo1 and combo2 private fields. Write a private method to respond to the action event of both combo. Switch on combo values. Note that you can access both combo directly because they are class fields